# PHP output script just putting 'row' instead of mysql rows?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my script for printing out stuff so I can make a list:

output.php = This is supposed to fetch the 'Name' column from the database and echo a table with the column 'Name'. Then it will try to filter the 'Name' Row with with filename.php.

```
<?php
include 'go.php';
$sql = "SELECT Name FROM utf";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<div class=\"CSSTableGenerator style=\"width:600px;height:150px;\"><table><tr><th>Name</th></tr></div>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        include 'filename2.php';
        echo "<tr><td>".$pics."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

My filename2.php: This is supposed to require the `seo function` and translate rows into something I can output. I have a feeling the issue is here?

```
<?php

    require_once ('seo.php');
    $name= $row["Price"];
    $pics = seo ($name);

?>
```

My seo.php:This removes all of the spaces and bad characters and optimizes their name:

```
<?php
function seo($string){
    $string = str_replace(array('[\', \']'), '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\[.*\]/U', '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/&(amp;)?#?[a-z0-9]+;/i', '-', $string);
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
    $string = preg_replace('/&([a-z])(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig|quot|rsquo);/i', '\\1', $string );
    $string = preg_replace(array('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '/[-]+/') , '-', $string);
    return strtolower(trim($string, '-'));
}

?>
```

The out put is just

Row

Row

Row

Row

Nothing else. What am I doing wrong here?

---

Fixed the code after a little bit of not being stupid:

```
<?php

include 'go.php';
include 'seo.php';
$sql = "SELECT Name FROM utf";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<div class=\"CSSTableGenerator style=\"width:600px;height:150px;\"><table><tr><th>Name</th></tr></div>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name = ('$row["Name"]');
            $seo2 = seo ($row["Name"]);
            $ext = '.jpg';
            $pics = $seo2 . $ext ;
        echo "<tr><td>".$pics."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Don't drink/smoke and try to code !

Comment: I dont't undestand - if you select only name, why do you want to get price from result?

Comment: You are echoing `$pics` inside your loop, not `$row` of something, what are you expecting?

Comment: Try to unify those files first. There's also no point in using `include` on a script that has `require_once`.. Try to convert the files into functions inside output.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here

Almost everything.

1. There is no such thing as `$row["Price"];` since you don't SELECT `Price`.
2. What's up with that weird include call? Will be repeated for each iteration.
3. `$pics` is always empty, hence you get blank rows for each iteration.

Why is `$pics` always empty? Because

```
$pics = seo ($name); // $name is blank, because of bullet 1.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! I'm a beginner so take it easy :) 

I fixed my code a bit:

`<?php
 require_once ('seo.php');
 $seo2 = seo ($row["Name"]);
 $ext = '.jpg';
 $pics = $seo2 . $ext ;
?>`
and it's working now. What do you suggest for the include call?

Comment: include seo.php in your main file only once. Then manipulate those variables right there in your loop, no need for filename2.php

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting 'Price' from your query..